# Install kendo ui using tsd type definition manager on command line

Tags: kendo-ui, typescript, angular

Does anyone know what I type to install kendo-ui tsd using the type definition manager on the command line?

According to [kendo](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/typescript) you put this in your app.ts file

```
/// <reference path="kendo.all.d.ts" />
```

which I did but now I need to get the corresponding file into my typings folder in my project.

When I tried this I got the message 'zero results':

```
tsd install kendo-all
```

Answer (score 7):

You have to type

```
tsd install kendo-ui
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this.  Frustrating that `tsd query kendo` returns nothing.